# why does file_put_contents insert 2 rows into json file?

Tags: php, json, file-put-contents

I have a JSON file as my database, I wrote this function for creating a new user row into the file:

```
function create(array $data)
{
    $tableFilePath = __DIR__ . "/storage/jsondb/users.json";
    $fileData = json_decode(file_get_contents($tableFilePath));
    $fileData[] = $data;
    $fileDataJson = json_encode($fileData);
    file_put_contents($tableFilePath, $fileDataJson);
}

create(['id' => rand(1, 100), 'name' => 'user' . rand(1, 100)]);
```

The problem is that when I call this function, I expect it inserts 1 row but it inserts 2 rows into the JSON file.

**UPDATE:**
my JSON file before running the code is an empty array:

```
[]
```

After running the code:

```
[{"id":28,"name":"user-3"},{"id":68,"name":"user-78"}]
```

as you can see, I executed the code one time, but it inserted two records into the JSON file.

**UPDATE-3**
I summarized my code because I wanted others can read it easily.
now it's my whole class that I wrote.
here is my interface:

```
interface CrudInterface
{
public function create(array $data) : int;
public function find(int $id): object;
public function get(array $columns,array $where):array;
public function update(array $data,array $where):int;
public function delete(array $where):int;
}
```

here I have abstract class `BaseModel` that implements `CrudInterface`:

```
abstract class BaseModel implements CrudInterface
{
protected $connection;
protected $table;
protected $pageSize = 10;
protected $attributes = [];
protected $primaryKey = 'id';

protected function __construct()
{
    # if mysql => set mysql connection
}

protected function getAttribute($key)
{
    if(!$key || array_key_exists($key, $this->attributes)){
        return null;
    }
    return $this->attributes[$key];
}
}
```

here `JsonBaseModel` that extends `BaseModel`:

```
 class JsonBaseModel extends BaseModel
    {
        private $dbFolder;
        private $tableFilePath;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->dbFolder = BASE_PATH . 'storage/jsondb/';
        $this->tableFilePath = $this->dbFolder . $this->table . '.json';
    }

    private function readTable()
    {
        $fileData = json_decode(file_get_contents($this->tableFilePath));
        return $fileData;
    }

    private function writeTable($fileData){
        $fileDataJson = json_encode($fileData); 
        file_put_contents($this->tableFilePath, $fileDataJson);

    }

    public function create(array $newData): int
    {
        $fileData = $this->readTable();
        $fileData[] = $newData;
        $this->writeTable($fileData);
        return $newData[$this->primaryKey];
    }

}
```

and here I have class `User` that extends `JsonBaseModel`:

```
class User extends JsonBaseModel
{
protected $table = 'users';
}
```

then I made an instance of `User` class and call it's `create()` function here:

```
$data = ['id' => rand(1, 100),'name' => "user-".rand(1, 100)];
$userModel = new User();
$userModel->create($data);
```

Comment: Please provide the original contents of users.json before you ran the code, and then the output you got in the file afterwards. It's quite hard to know what to expect when we can't see what was there originally.

Comment: @ADyson I updated my post, you can see before and after the json file.

Comment: The only logical explanation I can see so far, is that the code you have shown runs twice for some reason. What is the context in which this executes?

Comment: `$fileData[] = $data;` adds another occurance to the existing array. So you MUST have the first record already in the `users.json` file OR you are running `create()` twice

Comment: Something else is happening that is not apparent here that is calling the function twice. What happens if you dump the contents of $data at the top of the function, then run it? Do you see two outputs?

Comment: As you are generating the data in the call to the function and not inside the function, and the data in NOT the same, there are only 2 possibilities!! A record already exists in the file or you are calling the `create()` function twice somehow

Comment: @CBroe You are true. I wrote my code in another file and it inserts only 1 row. I updated my post. please check it.

Comment: `new User()`...what does that class do? What does its `create()` function do? In your code you only showed the `JsonBaseModel` class. Also where does `$this->primaryKey` come from. We're some way off having a [mre] yet. No-one could run the code you've provided and be sure what it would do.

Comment: @RiggsFolly you are right. when I run the code with code runner in vs code, it only adds 1 row, but when I run it from my browser it adds 2 rows.(I use XAMPP)

Comment: You are still not showing us the whole story `$this->tableFilePath = $this->dbFolder . $this->table . '.json';` Where does `$this->table` come from????

Comment: `when I run it from my browser it adds 2 rows`...have your browser's Network tool open (with the preserve log option ticked) while you're running this code and note how many times it makes the same request to the server (i.e. the request which triggers the create() function, not just any request). If it's more than once, then the answer is likely to be somewhere in your front-end code.

Comment: @ADyson I updated my post and put all my codes there. also, I don't have any front-end code. I have made a virtual server by xampp, I made an instance of my class into my project in a index file and test my code in the browser. for example I dump them and see them in the browser

Comment: @RiggsFolly I updatet my post, please check it

Comment: So to test in your browser you just make a simple GET request to a specific URL by pasting it into the browser's address bar, is that what you're saying? There is no HTML or user interface?

Comment: @ADyson yes, exactly, also when I changed my project path, it is solved. I think It's because of my virtual server configs.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing in an array with the user details, then adding it to the current contents.

If there is already a entry in your file, you'll then have 2 entries.

Make sure that users.json is empty first.

Comment: It's empty, I updated my post, you can see that.

Comment: The function must be called twice then. Try calling it with specific values: create([id=>1 name => 'test']) for example and see if user 1/ test appears twice.

Comment: I updatet my post and put all the codes.

Comment: The new code looks like it's doing the same as the first code. So it still stands that create() must be called twice. Remove the $data variable from the call and try calling it with specific values: create([id=>1 name => 'test']), if it appears twice in your file then you can be sure that something else is going on that it causing it to be called twice.

Comment: Do you have a refresh header in your html or php (or a redirect) in your code that is causing it to load twice?

Comment: I changed my project directory and it solved it